# Smoothie amount decreases

Tags: smoothie

If I dont drink my smoothie straight away the amount of smoothie in my bottle seems to decrease by almost half. I normally make the smoothie in the morning and have it for my lunch at work.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: It's not a problem, just a phenomenon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you blitz your smoothie in the blender a certain amount of air is incorporated. This will naturally make its way back out over time, decreasing the volume of the overall mix.

Answer (score -1):

I have experienced the same. But it is great, it is not a problem at all.
That's all air the goes away from it.

Comment: this was already said in the other answer, please don't repeat the exact same information.